# How can I access "properties" of TempData in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a Student parameter introduced in one of the actions in the controller. I assigned this parameter to TempData["student"] and kept it so that I could use it in another action in the same controller. Now TempData["student"] has sub properties such as FirstName, LastName, Email etc. But since the compiler has no idea about these properties, when I say something like TempData["student"].FirstName in the other action, it throws a compiler error as expected. I initiated a new Student variable in the class level, but since the controller is visited everytime I call an action from the views, it initiates a new variable and resets the values everytime. So I need to access those properties using TempData["student"]. Any help will be appreciated.

Action where I assign values to TempData["student"]

```
    [ActionName("NewStudentSchedule")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewStudentSchedule_Submit(Student student)
    {
        TempData["student"] = student;
        TempData.Keep();

        if (TempData.Count() == 0 || TempData == null)
            ViewBag.Error = true;
        else
            ViewBag.Error = false;

        return View("Close");
    }
```

The way and the action I am trying to use the TempData values in

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult StudentApplicants(List<StudentApplicant> studentApplicant)
    {
        TempData.Keep();

            Models.Student newStudent = new Models.Student();
            newStudent.FirstName = TempData["student"].FirstName;
            newStudent.LastName = TempData["student"].LastName;
           
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: In your `StudentApplicants` action you can simply do: `var student = TempData["student"] as Student;`. Now you can use `student` variable and it will hold all the temp data which was set in `NewStudentSchedule_Submit` action

Comment: Glad it did! I will make it as an answer to help future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, in your `StudentApplicants` change your code to:

```
var student = TempData["student"] as Student;
```

Now you can use `student` variable and it will hold all the temp data which was set in `NewStudentSchedule_Submit`